# How do Bit Torrent search engines work?

Tags: search-engine

For a normal search engine, I understand that it regularly travel across the internet to gather web page information, and sometimes the web page can voluntarily submit to engines their latest updates. But how about BT search engines? These torrents cannot be simply find through viewing web pages. Then how do they work? User submit?

Answer (score 2):

A publisher submits their torrent to a tracker, and then distributes a link to the file on that tracker. Users in turn use that file to connect to the specified tracker and download that file; the tracker then gives a list of users who are sharing that file. The torrent search sites just list what trackers are available and what files can be found on what trackers, which are submitted by publishers.

However, I think this may be better suited to something like the superuser rather than stackoverflow...

Answer (score 2):

No, users do not submit torrents. As we made with our torrent search site http://tornado.li/, we've created different robots that scan all added torrent sites for new torrents and add them to database. The whole process is fully automated, only in this way it's possible to give a good choise of torrents.